# special price is not working fine while adding product into cart

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, special-price, import-products

While uploading products, special price given from Magento admin is working fine in product page.

But, in cart page it's taking actual price.

I had tried many answers from internet. But, still failed to solve. please help to fix it?

Comment: check for cart price rule from admin also you can debug it with path hint enable from admin.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, in multi store setup (2 websites with 1 store each). But it can have many causes.
In my case special price is not loaded correctly in quote item (cart/checkout) because the product is missing a row value in table **catalog_product_entity_decimal** for admin store.
Magento needs at least to have a `NULL` in column value for `store_id = 0`.

I cart/quote item Magento loads the product collection differently using:

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Collection/Abstract.php::_getLoadAttributesSelect().

The function is clear, it needs a row for store_id = 0 (admin store) in order to perform the SQL join.

I guess the issue is what part of the store's code (magento core or other) is deleting the admin store row for special price.

A workaround is to go to admin store in product edit and save empty value in special price: save first any number and than remove the number on second save. It will save a `NULL` value in the table `catalog_product_entity_decimal` for that product.